# jquery-globalize to get date and money in certain culture

Tags: jquery, jquery-globalize

I need to format date, number and money in a certain culture, which is stored on client side.

Is only globalize.js and cultures/globalize.culture.az.js and etc. enough or I should download any other scripts (download by NUGet from VStudio)

Please show examples of using it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've dealed with this question.
One need to put
 
    
in layout and call the following:
Globalize.format(val, "c2", language) for money

Answer (score 0):

To add date/time culture i need a bit injection in Globalize.js code
    `formatDate = function( value, format, culture ) {
    var cal = culture.calendar,
        convert = cal.convert,
        ret;
    if (!format || !format.length || format === "i") {

```
    if (culture && culture.name.length) {
        // {--begin inj
        ret = formatDate(value, cal.patterns.F, culture);
        return ret;
        // }--end inj
```

`So I got rusults:`
var d = new Date(Date.UTC(2012,02,30))
Globalize.format(d,'','ru')
`"30 марта 2012 г. 3:00:00"`
Globalize.format(d,'','en')`
"Friday, March 30, 2012 3:00:00 AM"